# Cache Not Invalidating

Tags: cache

Im using a pretty standard method for calling for entries, but with one small caveat in that I'm setting the limit inside a variable which is passed through to an include

so my index.twig file is like so

```
{% include 'homepage/_latest' with {'postCount' : 9} %}
```

and my `homepage/_latest` file has the following

```
{% cache %}
{% set latest = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(postCount ? postCount : 12) %}

<div class="entries entries--latest">

    {% for entry in latest %}

    {% include 'blocks/_entry-item-latest' %}

    {% endfor %}

</div>

{% endcache %}
```

Is that variable the issue for me/ I save a post and it doesnt know up on the homepage. I had it setup to invalidate every 15 minutes, but we put out 3-4 posts a day so theres no real need to invalidate that content every 15 minutes

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wouldn't affect it. What happens if you remove it as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you’d basically need it to store separate caches depending on the limit.

The way to do that would be to set a custom key on the `{% cache %}` tag with the [`using key`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache#using-key) param:

```
{% if postCount is not defined or not postCount %}
    {% set postCount = 12 %}
{% endif %}

{% cache using key "homepage/_latest:"~postCount %}
    {% set latest = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(postCount) %}
    ...
{% endcache %}
```